# Is this patent for the aesthetic of the iPad?

Tags: usd504889

"We claim the ornamental design for an electronic device, substantially as shown and described."

[image: "FIG. 1 is a top perspective view of an electronic device in accordance with the present design"]

[image: "FIG. 9 is an exemplary diagram of the use of the electronic device thereof the broken lines being shown for illustrative puposes [sic] only and form no part of the claimed design."]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. It is a "design patent" which is very different from what we normally think of a patent. "Regular" patents are called Utility patents. Design patents just cover the look of something, not the function.